# Xamarin Forms - Android APK Assets Path

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk

I'm having some issues with the location of the Assets bundled into the Android APK I've created using Visual Studio for Mac.

When I try to run the Project onto an Android Device it fails on App Startup with an Runtime Exception telling that one of the Fonts could not be found.

```
Font asset not found SFUIText-Regular.ttf
```

My fonts are located directly under Assets/

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\SFUIText-Medium.ttf" />
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\SFUIText-Regular.ttf" />
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\SFUIText-Heavy.ttf" />
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\SFUIText-Bold.ttf" />
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\SFUIText-Light.ttf" />
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\SFUIText-Semibold.ttf" />
    <AndroidAsset Include="Assets\SFUIText-BoldItalic.ttf" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

To figure out what is the issue i´ve analyzed the apk to see the Assets location. And there the path to the assets is messed up as it is using my root path as reference.

[APK Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti3a0.png)

This issue just occurred recently after upgrading my local Xamarin setup to the newest Xamarin Plugins of Visual Studio. It also affects previous versions of the application that did build without that issue earlier.
But this issue does not occurre if i create a plain new Xamarin Project.

Can someone give me a hint where i could find the configuration of the Assets path?

Thank you for the support!

Comment: Can you try to delete bin and obj folder and rebuild project , regenerate apk file and upload again ?

Comment: Thank you ColeX for the idea! Sadly this did not work out for me. The assets are still bundled on the wrong Path… i've deleted the bin and obj folder of the overall project as well as of the Android directory. I've also tried to get a new clean setup on a different Machine. With the same result.

Comment: Where you put the fonts in? Assets folder or a sub folder for Assets? Have you recheeck the BuildAction for the fonts? Does all set to `AndroidAsset`?

Comment: Thank you Wendy for the idea! The fonts are directly placed in the Assets folder. I´ve just checked again the BuildAction and all are set to `AndroidAsset` :/

Comment: I checked the screenshot you providded, you have one Assets folder which include the fonts inside assets folder. Change the Assets folder name from Assets  to fonts and then check the location again. Could you provide the location you used for the fonts in your code?

Comment: I have the same problem with the absolute assets path in the created APK. The last Xamarin.android version that works is `xamarin.android-12.0.0.3`. After downgrading to this version the error is gone. My guess is that there has been a change in copying assets. But since it works on a new project it must be some file leftovers.

Comment: Using Visual Studio for Mac 2022 and this build command, I was successful and was able to build APK and AAB.

`msbuild /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release /p:AndroidPackageFormat=apk /p:AndroidKeyStore=true /p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=androiddebugkey /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=android /p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=/Path/To/debug.keystore /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=android ./Demo.Android/Demo.Android.csproj`